# If I buy a Humble Bundle not beating the average, can I later pay more to beat it and get the extra games?

Tags: humble-bundle

So lets say, I buy the Humble Bundle with Android 7 (the current one at this moment), but I don't pay above the average, I obviously won't get the extra games.

But can I go back and pay more later to get the extra games if I already made a purchase? E.g. if I now pay $1, but later the average price is $4, will I only need to pay the remaining $3, or would I need to pay the full $4 on top of the $1?

Or will I need to make another purchase?

Also, since now for the second tier it is mandatory to have paid above the average, will I be able to pay more in the second week if I want the second tier games?

All this is because at the moment, I am not interested in the current extra games (Bards Tale, and Worms Reloaded), but if in the second week they add better games, I would like to be able to get them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Go to the specific page of your humble bundle, not your account.
There you will see a link to increase your purchase.

[image: Link Screenshot]

Clicking this link will open the payment options:

[image: Screenshot of Payment Options]

As you can see, it already "knows" how much you paid and you can top it up to any amount you wish or need to beat the average and after paying you will find the new keys below on the same page.

Comment: [According to the FAQ](http://support.humblebundle.com/customer/portal/articles/243214-can-i-add-more-to-my-payment-after-the-bundle-ends-), it seems to apply up to 30 days after it ends. I don't know if this affects whether or not you receive the extra games or not.

Comment: @Unionhawk As it does not tell that, I'd assume it only works as long as the sale is going on. But an assumption is not a good answer so I took it out.

Comment: Interest thing that part of the extra 30 days! But as you say, it is unclear if you would get extra "beta the average" games if you do it after the sale. I doubt it, but maybe I will ask them directly, and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: The average is the average at the time you paid, not at the time you would later pay.

Comment: It doesn't appear to know how much you already paid, actually, that's just the default amount. Also, it's not clear how much would the average be.

Comment: Take care that it is not always true. I just bought the 2nd tier of Focus Home Interactive 2 but now I cannot upgrade to 3rd tier. This is the message on summary page: _The "increase your order amount" feature has been disabled for this bundle. If you would like to ask for a refund and re-purchase the bundle at a higher price to receive more content or simply to further support the bundle, please contact our customer support team here._

Answer (score 5):

I can verify that after the sale goes away you can add up to the average and still receive the codes for the extra games.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that as long as the link is available to increase your amount and the info below your paid amount shows the 'Make sure your total is at least $6.00 to unlock The Alien Breed Trilogy and Worms Revolution Gold.' which is the case with the Team17 bundle I bought you should qualify for the bonus games, but I would assume it's only valid for as long as the link is available, which seems to be the 30 days quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Like Phat I too increased my total contribution after the sale had ended but within the 30 day period after the sale. I had initially beat the average on the 2K bundle to get the "green tier" games and increased the total to $20 to get two "blue tier games".

So as per your initially question and as Phat has verified you can indeed increase it to get "blue tier" games.

Too bad the humble bundle support service didn't answer your question and you missed out on getting your game. You can always hope for another Sega bundle in which Shogun 2 is included!

Comment: Or look out for their flash sale where they often rebundle items